# Object defined error with statement. Copy sheet data and paste into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code That copies information starting in cell A10 and goes until column J and goes through all the rows until there it runs out of data. The first column has to be populated and the rest are hit and miss. There may be data in the cell or there may not. That copied data is then transferred to another workbook and pasted over information on a current worksheet.

I need to find a way that will copy all the information regardless of the possibility of data being in the cell.

Also, in its current state at the `with shttocopy` section I receive an "application or object defined error" message.

Just to clarify I need every single cell that has data in column A starting at cell A10 down to the very last row that is populated and copy everything from there to column J ending in the same row that has data in column A. Then paste it into a worksheet in another workbook.

Here is the code...I hope I made sense

```
Sub UpdateCustomerInformation()

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String
Dim destSheet As Worksheet









' check if the source file is open
Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\\Service_job_PO\Customer Information - Query.xls")
If Ret = False Then
' if file is not open the open file
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\\Service_job_PO\Customer Information - Query.xls")
Else
'Just make it active
 'Workbooks("C:\stack\file1.xlsx").Activate
 Set wkbSource = Workbooks("Customer Information - Query.xls")
 End If

' check if the destination file is open
Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
If Ret = False Then
' if file is not open file
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Customer Information")
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")

With shttocopy
    .Range(.Range("A10"), .Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
    destSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'save and close file
wkbDest.Save
wkbDest.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Else
'destination file is open
'Just make it active
 Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Service Jobs.xlsm")
 Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Customer Information")
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")
With shttocopy
    .Range(.Range("A10"), .Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
    destSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End With





End If



End Sub

Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim nam As String

wbname = filename
On Error Resume Next

ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0: Isworkbookopen = False
Case 70: Isworkbookopen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
With shttocopy
    .Range(.Range("A10"), .Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
    destSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End With
```

For the end of range, you:

- start in A10
- go down to the last row with a value in column A
- go across to the last column in that row with a value

Since the last row is unlikely to be full, you will not get a full set of columns.

I do not like statements like this because I find them confusing and difficult to get right.  It is difficult to guess which bit is giving the error.

Use something like:

```
RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(XlUp).Row
```

to find the last row.  This will, for example, avoid problems if there there is no second row.  You know column J is the last column so how about:

```
With shttocopy
  .Range("A10:J" & LastRow).Copy _
               destSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
```